# Escape * wildcard character in Active Directory path

Tags: string, powershell, active-directory, escaping, wildcard

How do I escape `*` wildcard characters as a literal character using PowerShell?

Scenario:  I am trying to create a computer object using PowerShell in our AD.  I use the following command and it works perfectly

```
New-ADComputer -Name "ServerName1" -Path "OU=App,OU=DEV,OU=Server,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

However, I have another domain where our main servers OU has `*` in front of the word "Servers", like this: `*Servers`.  If I use the above command it doesn't work and after troubleshooting, I narrowed down and it fails because there is `*` front of "Servers".

```
New-ADComputer -Name "ServerName1" -Path "OU=App,OU=DEV,OU=*Server,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Error is:

```
New-ADComputer: The operation failed because of a bad parameter.
At line:1 char:5
+    New-ADComputer -Name "ServerName1" -Path "OU=App,OU=DEV,OU=*Server,$ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=mspgtestha08...C=viacom,DC=com:String) [New-ADComputer], ADPasswordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADComputer
```

I found another post and suggested to use backtick, and I have tried still get the error.

```
New-ADComputer -Name "ServerName1" -Path "OU=App,OU=DEV,OU=`*Server,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Comment: Normally, the backslash is used to escape characters in DistinghuishedNames. However.. [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx) site says the `*` does not nead escaping. Are you absolutely sure you are getting the correct path?

Comment: There is a literal, actual `*` at the start of your OU name? Why?

Comment: Scratch that question. I know it's technically possible to do that, and anything that is technically possible will eventually be done - it's just not a particularly good idea to do things like this.

Comment: If the name of that OU really starts with an asterisk, you may also try `\2A`. I suggest you open up ADUC, right-click the OU you need and go Properties. Then in the Attributes tab, scroll down to the `distinghuishedName` property. Double-click and copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of characters that are reserved in LDAP search filters (`*`, `(`, `)`, `\`, `/`, and the null byte). Any character *can* be escaped in an LDAP query, but those reserved ones *must* be escaped.

Escape codes are described in the MSDN under [Active Directory Search Filter Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSI/search-filter-syntax#special-characters), but generally it's a backslash plus the hex character code. For the `*` the character code is `2a`, so the escape code is `\2a`.

This:

```
New-ADComputer -Name "ServerName1" -Path "OU=App,OU=DEV,OU=\2aServer,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

would work.